# Set cookie in Xamarin Android WebView

Tags: cookies, webview, xamarin.android

In Xamarin Android SDK 30, when trying to set webview cookie does not work.

string cookieString = string.Format("{0}={1}; path=/;domain={2}; secure; ", Strings.SessionCookie, encryptedCookie, "value");

```
                if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
                {
                    CookieManager.Instance.SetAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    CookieManager.Instance.SetAcceptCookie(true);  //this function doesn't work from lollipop(API21) and above
                }
                CookieManager.Instance.SetCookie(RootCookieDomain, cookieString);

                webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                webView.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
                webView.LoadUrl(Link);
```

The above code works perfectly in SDK 29 but as soon as its switched to 30 it stops working and cookie is not being set.

Answer (score 1):

I set the cookie with the code below. It works on API30.

Xaml:

```
<WebView x:Name="MyWebview" WidthRequest="400" HeightRequest="500"></WebView>
        <Button Text="click to load" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
```

Code:

```
  private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        Uri uri = new Uri("https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/xamarin", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

        Cookie cookie = new Cookie
        {
            Name = "XamarinCookie",
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
            Value = "My cookie",
            Domain = uri.Host,
            Path = "/"
        };
        cookieContainer.Add(uri, cookie);
        MyWebview.Cookies = cookieContainer;
        MyWebview.Source = new UrlWebViewSource { Url = uri.ToString() };
    }
```

Comment: It's important to note that the Uri that you specific must be absolute even if you set the UriKind to RelativeOrAbsolute.

IE
CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
Uri uri = new Uri("domain.com", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
Cookie cookie = new Cookie
{
    Name = "test",
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
    Value = "my cookie"
};
cookieContainer.Add(uri, cookie); //<---- This will throw an exception saying it cannot be done using a relative Uri.